# boost bimap set_of with user defined comparator

Tags: c++, boost, bimap

I plan to use my own compare function with boost bimap. The issue i am trying to address is when i use  boost bimap with a pointer, the comparison should not compare the two pointers but should compare the class which is pointed by the pointer.

I tried the following code. But it doesn't even compile. What am i doing wrong? Also is there a simpler way to achieve less function that compares two objects and not two pointers pointers)

```
typedef std::set<int> ruleset;

template <class myclass>
bool comp_pointer(const myclass &lhs, const myclass &rhs)
{
    return ((*lhs) < (*rhs));
}

typedef boost::bimap<set_of<ruleset *, comp_pointer<ruleset *> >, int> megarulebimap;
```

Error messages:

party1.cpp:104:64: error: type/value mismatch at argument 2 in template parameter list for 'template struct boost::bimaps::set_of'
party1.cpp:104:64: error:   expected a type, got 'comp_pointer'
party1.cpp:104:70: error: template argument 1 is invalid
party1.cpp:104:85: error: invalid type in declaration before ';' token

Comment: typedef std::set<int> ruleset;
struct ruleset_cmp {
    bool operator()(const ruleset *lhs, const ruleset *rhs) const
    {
        return ((*lhs) < (*rhs)); 
    }
};

typedef boost::bimap<set_of<ruleset *, ruleset_cmp>, int> megarulebimap; -- this snippet works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
typedef std::set<int> ruleset;

struct ruleset_cmp {
    bool operator()(const ruleset *lhs, const ruleset *rhs) const
    {
        return ((*lhs) < (*rhs));
    }
};

typedef boost::bimap<set_of<ruleset *, ruleset_cmp>, int> megarulebimap;
```

Okay. The above snippet works. It appears a functor needs to be used here.